# Windows Forms click event not fired when clicking on label?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have `Windows Form` *TestForm*, and in my `Form` I have several labels that are only used to display some text.

I need to display a `MessageBox.Show` anytime the `Form` is clicked. So I have an `event handler` for the click, which looks like this:

```
private void TestForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The form has been clicked");
}
```

Unfortunately, the click event doesn't fire when I click over a label in the `Form`. Is there a way to fix this, besides consuming the click event for the labels?

Thanks.

Comment: Double click on the `Label` and write your code in the `label_click` event.

Comment: Is that the only solution? To capture the click event of each label?

Comment: You can add the same click event to all labels, but yes, they all need to know what you want..

Comment: What @S.Akbari is saying is, to make the `Label` auto-generate an event handler in code, double-click on it in design view. You will then be taken to the codebehind with a `Button_Click` event ready to implement. If you've already got your code in the code-behind (as above), you need to make sure you add the event to all of your labels. Click the Properties, and ensure that the `Click` event is wired to use your `TestForm_Click` handler you've made; for of each the labels you want to handle the click for

Comment: ...or just draw your labels.

Comment: Put the labels in, say, a `List<Label>` then iterate over this list and attach the click event that way. Or just dynamically create your `Label`s using a loop.

Comment: call the `TestForm_Click` event in the `label1_Click` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To use the same click event for all labels:**

In the properties for each label, go to the `Events` (lightning bolt tab).

You will see (probably near the top) a label for `Click`, click the dropdown for this event, and you will be shown a list of handlers that you could use for that label.

Here's the Properties > Events > Click handler (bottom right):

[image: The properties / events box for the label]

Because all of your labels are of the same type, and produce the same `EventArgs`, you are able to use the same handler for all of them.

Then, when you are adding more `Label`s, just choose the event handler from the `Click` event dropdown:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To flesh out LarsTech's comment, I have used something like this in the past when I was having problems with labels overlapping each other and lack of true transparency in WinForms. What I did was make the labels invisible on the Form, then iterate through them in the Form's paint event, pull the information out of them and then use `Graphics.DrawString` to draw the text. That way you you will still be able see them in design mode.

This is a quick example of what I mean.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var temp in this.Controls)
        {
            if (temp is Label) //Verify that control is a label
            {
                Label lbl =(Label)temp;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(lbl.Text, lbl.Font, new SolidBrush(lbl.ForeColor), new Rectangle(lbl.Location, lbl.Size));
            }
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The Form has been clicked");
    }
}
```